# How to left outer join next tables?

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `publications` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numerated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `collection_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `note` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `adminNote` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `collectionId` (`collection_id`)
  KEY `numerated` (`numerated`),
) ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `publication_numerations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `publication_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `book` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `publication_id` (`publication_id`)
) ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `properties` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `publication_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `publication_id` (`publication_id`)
)
```

All I need is to have list of all records from table publications and publication_numerations. Tryed with cake bake model/controller/view, but all the time it joins 
publications and properties, without publication_numerations.

Can you help me to solve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

UPDATED: so, all I need is to create and use it as default query:

```
SELECT * FROM `publications` 
LEFT JOIN `publication_numerations` ON (`publications`.`id` = publication_numerations.`publication_id`)
```

UPDATED: here are my models

1. publications model

   ```
       var $hasOne = array(
           'Publisher' => array(
               'className' => 'Publisher',
               'foreignKey' => 'publication_id',
               'conditions' => '',
               'fields' => '',
               'order' => ''
           ), 
       );

       var $belongsTo = array(
           'Collection' => array(
               'className' => 'Collection',
               'foreignKey' => 'collection_id',
               'conditions' => '',
               'fields' => '',
               'order' => ''
           )
       );

       var $hasMany = array(
           'PublicationProperty' => array(
               'className' => 'PublicationProperty',
               'foreignKey' => 'publication_id',
               'dependent' => false,
               'conditions' => '',
               'fields' => '',
               'order' => '',
               'limit' => '',
               'offset' => '',
               'exclusive' => '',
               'finderQuery' => '',
               'counterQuery' => ''
           ),
           'PublicationNumeration' => array(
               'className' => 'PublicationNumeration',
               'foreignKey' => 'publication_id',
               'conditions' => '',
               'fields' => '',
               'order' => ''
           )
       );

   }
   ?>
   ```
2. PublicationNumeration model

   `var $belongsTo = array(
       'Publication' => array(
           'className' => 'Publication',
           'foreignKey' => 'publication_id',
           'conditions' => '',
           'fields' => '',
           'order' => ''
       )
   );

   var $hasMany = array(
       'Publication' => array(
           'className' => 'Publication',
           'foreignKey' => 'publication_id',
           'conditions' => '',
           'fields' => '',
           'order' => ''
       )
   );`


   }
   ?>
3. Collection modes

   `var $hasMany = array(
       'Property' => array(
           'className' => 'Property',
           'foreignKey' => 'collection_id',
           'dependent' => false,
           'conditions' => '',
           'fields' => '',
           'order' => '',
           'limit' => '',
           'offset' => '',
           'exclusive' => '',
           'finderQuery' => '',
           'counterQuery' => ''
       ),
       'Publication' => array(
           'className' => 'Publication',
           'foreignKey' => 'collection_id',
           'dependent' => false,
           'conditions' => '',
           'fields' => '',
           'order' => '',
           'limit' => '',
           'offset' => '',
           'exclusive' => '',
           'finderQuery' => '',
           'counterQuery' => ''
       )
   );`


   }
   ?>

Answer (score 2):

You can do joins in cake like so:

```
$joins = array(
     array('table' => 'publication_numerations',
       'alias' => 'PublicationNumeration',
       'type' => 'LEFT',
       'conditions' => array(
          'Publication.id = PublicationNumeration.publication_id',
       )
     )
);

$this->Publication->find('all', array('joins' => $joins));
```

Comment: tnx, this is useful, but i need a bit more help...

it's because sql that is generated on your way returns 59 rows and that is ok. but in cakephp application, on index view it returns 53 rows. here is my code:

$joins = array( array('table' => 'publication_numerations', 'alias' => 'PublicationNumeration', 'type' => 'LEFT', 'conditions' => array( 'Publication.id = PublicationNumeration.publication_id' ) ) );
$this->Publication->find('all', array('joins' => $joins));
$this->set('publications', $this->paginate());
$this->set(compact('publications'));

can you tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Basically it means that some Publications have more than one  PublicationNumerations. So when the PublicationNumerations are returned, some Publications are displayed more than once. What you need to do is figure out what data you really want and adjust the SQL accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Tryed with cake bake
>   model/controller/view, but all the
>   time it joins publications and
>   properties, without
>   publication_numerations.

So, create associations manually - [Associations: Linking Models Together](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together). It does not seems that you need 'joins'. By setting associations correctly you will be able to get the list you need by using `find('list')` in your controller - http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data#find-list-1022.

Comment: can you check my models? i have updated my original post with them. for me they looks ok; that's why i asked for help here... tnx!

Comment: It is not clear from your update what models associations have you posted. Add the model name for each stack. But I guess the first stack is for `publications` table. It seems for me that there is an error in hasMany association. You have 'PublicationProperty' there but the table name is `properties` so the correct class name should be 'Property'. Post the associations for all 3 models, please.

Comment: ok, there are all three models. code is rendered by forum, so it's missing escape tag, <?php

Comment: If PublicationNumeration hasAndBelongsToMany you will need to have another table with both foreign keys: 'publication_id' and 'publication_numeration_id'.PublicationNumeration hasMany association assumes that there is a foreign key 'publication_numeration_id' in 'publications' table but there is none.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the *type* attribute of *$join* array **'LEFT OUTER'** instead of **'LEFT'**.